# Imgur API call: 443 ENOTFOUND error troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, imgur

I'm receiving the same error every time I call the following node.js code. I haven't used Authorization Headers before in node.js, so I must be doing something wrong. Help or point me towards good documentation? The code is trying to retrieve as search for 'yellow' in imgur's library. My console always prints the same ENOTFOUND error each time I try to run it.

```
var express = require("express");
var moment = require("moment");
var http = require("http");
var express = require("express");
var moment = require("moment");
var https = require("https");
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var mystatus="";
var app=express();

var imgurClientID = "<my id>";
var imgurClientSecret = "<my client secret>";

var options = {
    hostname: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/search?q=yellow',
    method: "POST",
    headers:{
       Authorization: imgurClientID, 
    }
}

app.get('/home', function(req,res){
var myreq = https.request(options, function(res){
    console.log('Status: '+res.statusCode);
    console.log('Headers: '+JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(body){
        console.log("Body: "+body);
    });
});
myreq.on('error', function(e){
    console.log("Error!: "+e);
})

myreq.end();

});

// https.get("https://Client-ID:"+imgurClientID+"@api.imgur.com/3/gallery/search?q=yellow", function(res){
//     res.setHeader("Client-ID", imgurClientID);
//     var body = "";
//     res.on('data', function(chunk){
//         body+=chunk;
//     });

//     res.on('end', function(){
//         var imgurRes = JSON.parse(body);
//         console.log(imgurRes);
//     });
// }).on('error', function(e){
//     console.log("Error!: "+e);
// })

app.get('/new/:name*', function(req,res){
    //detect if name is a URL
    //if it is not a proper http, return 'could not load' status
    if (req.params.name.substr(0,4).toLowerCase() != "http")
        {
        mystatus = "Could not load";
        res.json({url_part1: req.params.name,
                 url_part2: req.params[0],
                 status: mystatus
            });

        }
    http.get(req.params.name+req.params[0], function(thisres){
        var wwwpath = req.params[0].substr(2, req.params[0].length-2);

        //do not look for the site unless it returns a 200 status code
        if (thisres.statusCode != 200){
            loadstatus = "Could not load";
        }

        //otherwise, find the site in the MongoDB list!
        else {
            //indicate that the site is a working URL
            loadstatus = "Loaded!";

            //prepare the database
            mongo.connect("mongodb://dickorydock:$iderHouseRul3z@ds145365.mlab.com:45365/urlrosetta", function(err, db) {
                var shorturl = db.collection("shorturl");
                //find maximum site number
                shorturl.find().sort({site_number:-1}).limit(1).toArray(function(err,documents){
                    max_site_number = documents[0]["site_number"];
                })
                //look for the site in the existing database
                shorturl.find(
                   {original_url: wwwpath}
                 , {_id: 0, original_url: 1,short_url: 1, site_number:1})
                .toArray(function(err,documents){    
                    //if we found it, no need to add it again -- just return the existing site number
                    if (documents.length>0){
                        var sitenumber = documents[0]["site_number"];
                    }
                    //if we didn't find the working URL, add it
                    else {
                        var sitenumber = max_site_number + 3;
                        var newsitejson={original_url: wwwpath, site_number: sitenumber}
                        shorturl.insert(newsitejson)
                    }

                    //return the info about the short link
                    res.json({original_url:  req.params.name+"://"+wwwpath,
                        short_url: "http://dickorydock-shorturl.herokuapp.com/"+sitenumber
                        });
                  db.close()
                })
            })
        }

    })
    //if there is an error in finding the site in the URL, return 'could not load' status
    .on('error', function(e){
        console.error(e.code);
        res.json({error: "Not a valid URL - try again."})          
    })
})


app.get('/:shortnum*', function(req,res){
   var sitenumber = parseInt(req.params.shortnum);
   var siteextra = req.params[0];
   if (siteextra.length > 0){
        res.json({error: "Not a valid reference - try again."})
   }
   else {
    mongo.connect("mongodb://dickorydock:$iderHouseRul3z@ds145365.mlab.com:45365/urlrosetta", function(err, db) {
        var shorturl = db.collection("shorturl");
        //look for the site in the existing database, and either redirect or give an error
        shorturl.find(
           {site_number: sitenumber}
         , {_id: 0, original_url: 1, site_number:1})
        .toArray(function(err,documents){ 
            if (documents.length>0){
            res.redirect("http://"+documents[0]["original_url"])
            }
            else if (documents.length == 0){
                res.json({error: "Not a valid reference - try again."})
            }
          db.close()
         })

    })

    }

})
app.listen(8080, function(){
//app.listen(process.env.PORT, function(){
    console.log("App listening")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var options = {
    hostname: 'api.imgur.com',
    path: '/3/gallery/search?q=yellow',
    method: "POST",
    headers:{
       Authorization: imgurClientID, 
    }
}
```

you are getting that error because it's trying to hit https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/search?q=yellow:443, the above should send it to the right location